# Jenkins slave return the exited code 143 even successfully run

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jnlp, docker-container

I have the Jenkins master server to provision the test jobs to the pool of Jenkins slave, which is AWS EC2 instance running Docker container. The job is provisioned and run properly on slave nodes and checking the console log on Jenkins Master, I'm able to see they're successfully run and finished (which i expected for each successfully job, it should return exited code 0)

However, when I **ssh-ing** to the container instances and check the docker container via

```
docker ps -aq -f status=exited | xargs docker inspect --format {{.State}}
```

Almost 99% of the container returned the exited code 143 and some returned exited code 255. 
Taking a deep dive into one of the container exited with code 143, the state info is as below

```
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 143,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-12-02T14:48:18.066029305Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-12-02T14:49:42.881201067Z"
```

My first doubt is due to the OOM, but in the stats, it showed OOMKilled = false, so it's not the problem here

So i came to check the Docker logs

```
Warning: JnlpProtocol3 is disabled by default, use JNLP_PROTOCOL_OPTS to alter the behavior
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: xxx
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:18 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 3.20
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
WARNING: No Working Directory. Using the legacy JAR Cache location: /root/.jenkins/cache/jars
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among xxx
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP4-connect, Ping]
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: xxx
  Agent port:    44573
  Identity:     xxx
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to xxx
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:19 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: xxx
Dec 02, 2019 3:29:20 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Dec 02, 2019 3:30:14 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

Looks like it does not have any helpful information here, since the logs showed the connection established successfully between Jenkins master & slave, the slave run the job then the Slave node is terminated.

So my question is there anything else I can check to see why the successful job execution `result exit code=0` does not return its expected code but 143 / something else?

Comment: Pretty late to this question. What about the docker exit codes? Docker exit code `143` means `Container received a SIGTERM` signal. It could be due to the fact that the process sent a signal to gracefully terminate it, given that the last line of the log states `Terminated`.